# Does CDN and Bandwidth in Azure are the same?

Tags: azure

I just like to confirm if CDN and Bandwidth in Azure are the same? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. CDN and Bandwidth are entirely different concepts. CDN stands for Content Delivery Network which allows you to serve your blob storage contents from a server closest to your application user. More about CDN here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network. Bandwidth is the amount of data transferred (usually in bytes).

Comment: I'll check your link :) Thanks for your reply :)